# EGOTextView compatible with apple

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, text

Does apple support EGOTextView ? Or the app is rejected which includes EGOTextView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your App would get rejected for using EGOTextView. Its written using CoreText, QuartzCore public API's. I don't see a reason why an App should be rejected for using EGOTextView.
https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView/blob/master/EGOTextView/EGOTextView.h